# display bootstrap dropdown-menu to orient the list to the left instead of right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have an issue with the button dropdown from Bootstrap-Twitter 3.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7ts0wk9c/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <!-- Split button -->
    <div class="input-group-btn">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the JSFiddle above, you can see an input stick with a dropdown button at its right.

The problem is that the list of the dropdown button is displayed in a way that the list is cutted (the viewport should not expand itself, however this is what happens).

**Question**

How can I tell this element to display the list from the right to the left (reverse of the current behaviour) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns):

> By default, a dropdown menu is automatically positioned 100% from the top and along the left side of its parent. Add `.dropdown-menu-right` to a `.dropdown-menu` to right align the dropdown menu.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <!-- your li elements... -->
</ul>
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7ts0wk9c/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Try Use :

`class="dropdown-menu pull-right"`

As you can see here : [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ts0wk9c/1/)

This will ensure the `dropDown` menu is pulling to the right, which gives it `float:right!important`.

This will ensure it's not hidden behind.

**EDIT**: *Rory McCrossan's answer is the recommended solution for this question*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by CSS (overwrite the default rule) or you can custom with a new class:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  right:0;
  left: auto;
}
```

In fact is the same thing this class `.pull-right` from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) library do:

**CSS**

```
.pull-right {
  right:0;
  left: auto;
}
```